# 'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command while executing Jenkins file

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have a very basic `Jenkins pipeline` that builds a `Java` project and deploys the artifact to an `EC2` instance.

The build part is working fine but the deployment is not working and giving an error related to `scp`.

I copy pasted the entire `scp` command present in my `Jenkinsfile` onto the `Windows` command prompt to see if that works and copies over the jar to `ec2` instance successfully, and it did work.

[image]

Not sure why it is not working through `Jenkins`.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        tools {
            maven "Maven3"
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build and Deploy') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        def os = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase()
                        echo "OS: ${os}"                
                        if (os.contains("linux")) {
                          sh "mvn clean install -DskipTests" 
                        } else {
                          bat "mvn clean install -DskipTests"
                          bat "scp -i C:\\Users\\Nital\\.ssh\\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem target\\helloworld-rest-app.jar ec2-user@35.175.125.176:/home/ec2-user/app-deploys"
                        }
                    }
                }
                post {
                    success {
                        echo 'Build and Deploy - SUCCESS'
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

**Windows Command Prompt:**

```
C:\Users\Nital>scp
usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target
```

**Jenkins Error Log:**

```
[INFO] Installing C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\helloworld-rest-app-build\pom.xml to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository\com\example\helloworld-rest-app\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\helloworld-rest-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.991 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-25T00:11:10-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\helloworld-rest-app-build>scp -i C:\Users\Nital\.ssh\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem target\hellworld-rest-app.jar ec2-user@35.175.125.176:/home/ec2-user/app-deploys 
'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Sounds like scp is not in the path of the user which runs Jenkins

Comment: `Jenkins` is on the same local machine which is `Windows 10`. I have updated my original question with a screenshot which shows that I can manually copy the `JAR` to `EC2` using `SCP`

Comment: Is Jenkins running with your user ID? How was `scp` added to your shell's PATH environment?

Comment: I just saw that it `scp` was getting picked from `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH' which I think could have gotten installed with some other program. I added this folder to PATH variable also and then ran the build job again just now but no luck. Why is Jenkins not able to pick this scp.exe whereas Windows command prompt is able to? Is there any configuration in Jenkins that needs to be done as well?

Comment: Yes Jenkins is running with the same user ID and it is installed on the same Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Can you please exho out the path in your Jenkins build script and take a look if the OpenSSH path is there

Comment: On Windows 10 i tried to use absolute path like this :`c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe -r styleguide www@192.168.X.Z:/srv/folder` but does not work, however, it works fine on powershell CLI

Answer (score 1):

It's because the executable is in the Windows System32 directory and due to security concerns, is not accessible from scripts.  If you copy the `ssh` and `scp` executables out of the windows directory and put the new directory into your path it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `scp` something from Windows, then why not simply use `pscp` to achieve this?

install PuTTY, which includes also PSCP (SCP for Windows).

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

please select the latest version of MSI (‘Windows Installer’) for your computer (32-bit or 64-bit)

If you want to use it in a Java program, then here is an example: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html

Comment: I certainly can try that if the above question does not have a solution. It  is just beyond my understanding as to why that thing is working through command prompt and not through Jenkins which is also installed on the same machine.

Comment: @user2325154 Can you try with the full path of `scp` like `C:\Program Files\PuTTY\scp -i C:\Users\Nital\.ssh\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem target\hellworld-rest-app.jar ec2-user@35.175.125.176:/home/ec2-user/app-deploys`

Comment: I don't see any scp.exe in C:\Program Files\PuTTY\ folder hence I think the above command will fail.

Comment: scp.exe is present in C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH folder. I tried adding the full path and running the build job again but no luck

Comment: I got this error message after trying installing pscp. `# pscp -i C:\Users\Nital\.ssh\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem target\helloworld-rest-app.jar ec2-user@35.175.125.176:/home/ec2-user/app-deploys
Unable to use key file "C:\Users\Nital\.ssh\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem" (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format))
Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before you execute any of the commands like scp etc.

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Set this in Jenkinsfile? I am using Windows OS hence I will try Windows equivalent of the above command

Answer (score -1):

Scp command used to securely transfer files between two Linux/Unix computers systems

> The syntax for the scp command is:

```
scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2
```

and in order to use scp command in windows use pscp:

```
pscp c:\documents\info.txt userid@server.example.com:/tmp/foo/info.txt
```

Please  go through the articular

https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-putty

Comment: I got this error message after installing pscp. # pscp -i C:\Users\Nital\.ssh\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem target\helloworld-rest-app.jar ec2-user@35.175.125.176:/home/ec2-user/app-deploys Unable to use key file "C:\Users\Nital\.ssh\LightsailDefaultKey-us-east-1.pem" (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format)) Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)